# Malloc Member Array of Struct

Tags: c, arrays, struct, malloc

I have a struct and an dynamic array inside the struct. I want to malloc this array but i don't really now how. I want that array void because i want the members of this array to be structs. As you can see i tried something but it doesn't really work

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct saf 
{
  int head;
  void **stack;
  int size;
}exp1;



void init(int n)
{

   struct saf exp1->stack = malloc(n);

}

int main()
{

 printf("Give size: ");
 scanf("%d",&exp1.size);
 init(exp1.size);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: what error does it give you?

Comment: "ivalid type argument of '->' (have 'struct saf')"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

exp1 isn't a pointer. Use

```
exp1.stack = malloc(n);
```

Comment: Yes this is it . Thank you so much, what a fool i am

Answer (score 2):

I believe you are looking for `void *`, e.g.,

```
void init (int n)
{
    exp1->stack = malloc(sizeof(void *) * n);
}
```

You will have to cast it when you use it.

Comment: It doesn't work,maybe i am missing something. Should i change something in struct?

Answer (score 0):

struct saf exp1.stack = malloc(n);

The above statement creates array of *n* memory locations and returns the *void ** pointer to the starting address. In this case *stack* should be single pointer i,e void *stack;
If you want *stack* to be a double pointer i,e void **stack then you should use

exp1.stack=malloc(sizeof(void *)*n);